# NewsFeed text boxes - slow typing performance in Chrome

Tags: newsfeed, chrome

My users who are running Chrome are finding that making a post on the newsfeed to be quite painful because as they type into the text boxes the text they are typing frequently does not appear until several seconds after they have pressed the keys on their keyboard.

Here is what I have noticed:

1. It's not consistent as far as when it happens.
2. It can be normal typing the first 3 words and then the last half of the sentence will
   be delayed. But normally it is at the start of the sentence.
3. I see nothing in the Chrome debugger or in the network screen of the Chrome debug tools to explain what might be going wrong.